# jQuery DIV scroll on page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
    var offset = $(".control.Home .rightCol").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $(".control.Home .rightCol").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $(".control.Home .rightCol").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        };
    });
});
});
```

When i scroll down the page the right hand side div keeps scrolling down. Its on the localhost so cant show you a link at the moment. How do i make the div stop at a certain point to where ever the left hand side div stops?

Website: http://goo.gl/OSiH5

Link has been added to where you can see the div scrolling. I need it to stop before the footer where you have the scrolling icons

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you trying to create an element that's always "on screen", i.e. stops scrolling when reaching the top of the page. If so, this is not the way to do it?

Comment: A fiddle, or at the very least some markup, would help out a lot.

Comment: are you trying to keep the right column in the same place?  if so, you can try using position:fixed

Comment: I'll have to provide you with jsFiddle or HTML Markup. Will have to update on Monday - just left the office. Apologies for not being clearer. Trying to scroll div up and down on page scroll and make it stop at the top or bottom of where the site ends.

Comment: This is done by websites everywhere, and it's quite simple. It normally uses a swap between position fixed and relative/absolute, as noted by Pete above, and some tricky positioning. There are numerous plugins that do this if you're not sure how to do it yourself.

Comment: @adeneo i will have a look over the weekend at plugins and try some examples out. Will update this on Monday now.

Comment: Link has been added to where you can see the div scrolling. I need it to stop before the footer where you have the scrolling icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this code in one of my sites:

```
var scroll = 0;
var marginTop = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

        $("#left").animate({"marginTop": marginTop+"px"}, {duration:500,queue:false} );
    });  
});
```

`#left` is the div I move up/down following the scroll.

*You can see it live: realtimecoding.net*

**Edit:**
If you need it to stop scrolling at, lets say, 660px you can just add a verification. It should look like:

```
var scroll = 0;
var marginTop = 10;
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (marginTop<660) {
            $("#left").animate({"marginTop": marginTop+"px"}, {duration:500,queue:false} );
        }
    });  
});
```

So that it never goes above 660px margin top.

Comment: nice - but if you keep scrolling with the mouse-wheel it jumps and down making it scroll even further down. How do you stop it to where your content on the right ends?

Comment: does i've added the if statement in but doesnt seem to work for me here is the script                                                               $(document).ready(function () {

                /*} else {
                   if (marginTop < 660) {
                    $(".control.Home .rightCol").animate({ "marginTop": marginTop + "px" }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
                }*/

Comment: I've posted the entire script. It should work, I've tested it! =)

Comment: And pixel wise you was about 20px off where i wanted it to stop - Awesome work dude! Much Appreciated!

Comment: When I tried this code Safari was going/scrolling to the top. Do have an idea why this would happen? I was not moving the div just started scrolling Safari to the top of the page (where the div is located).